# Can't find field level annotations in a ClassDeclaration

Tags: java, openrewrite

I'm parsing this string:

```java
        rewriteRun(
          spec -> spec
            .parser(JavaParser.fromJavaVersion().classpath("lombok")
                .logCompilationWarningsAndErrors(false)),
          // language=java
          java(
            """
              import lombok.Getter;
              import lombok.Setter;
              
              @Getter
              public class A {
              
                  public A() {
                      
                  }
                  
                  @Setter
                  private int i;
              }
              """
...
```

But I have trouble locating the annotations in my `visitClassDeclaration`.
`classDecl.type.getAnnotations()` is `null` and `classDecl.type.getMembers().get(0).getAnnotations()` is empty.
`classDecl.getAnnotations()` has only one field: `classDecl` itself (`classDecl.getAnnotations().t == classDecl`)
`classDecl.getLeadingAnnotations()` has the getter, but I cannot find the setter.
Where is the Setter?
Why are the annotations under `classDecl.type` empty/null?

Answer (score 0):

Can we zoom out a bit on what you're trying to achieve on a higher level? That might help give direction to what I recommend. And what version of OpenRewrite are you using?

We recently added [an AnnotationService abstraction](https://github.com/search?q=repo%3Aopenrewrite%2Frewrite%20AnnotationService&type=code) that might help for instance, or the [static FindAnnotations.find](https://github.com/search?q=repo%3Aopenrewrite%2Frewrite%20FindAnnotations.find&type=code) method depending on your use case.

Hope either of that helps you already; we also have a public Slack that you're welcome to join for followup questions.